# Orientation portrait and landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage

I have a 2 big logo images. In landscape mode all OK. When I change to portrait mode, the images lay one on the other. They too big for IB alignment 
Can I set different views for each orientation?
or how can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update to saadnib's answer. Do not use `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`. This method is for something else.

Your methods are:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

The former is called just before rotation occurs and the second one is called just after interface orientation.

You should replace UIViewController's view here or you can replace images for different orientations here too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following  code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

for current orientation and according it change your image view frames.

Comment: I also try playing here, but the only thing that came to mind to use different images for different orientation

Comment: yes you have to use different images for different orientation.